Configuring Firebase in node red
I am doing a project on IOT and I'm using Firebase Realtime Database as the database in Node red but I cannot connect these two together. I am using node-red-contrib-firebase to connect with firebase


"My information" gets data from a form in node red including name, student id, class id.
I don't understand what I did wrong because I tried to copy the URL into Firebase field, change the firepath into My Information but it cannot work. Am I misunderstanding something?

Please edit the question to be explicit about which firebase node-red node you are using as there are many, but if it has the hard coded URL, you should raise an issue with that node's maintainer to update it to support all available URLs.

The GitHub page for the node suggests it's not been touched in 9 years. I suggest looking at the other nodes on flows.nodered.org

It looks like Node-RED can only accept Firebase Realtime Database URLs that end in firebaseio.com. This means that you need to ensure that your Firebase database (and possibly the entire project) is created in the US, while the one in your project is in the Asia location.
So step by step:

Create a new project with a database in the United States (us-central-1) location.
Copy the project ID from the Project settings.
Paste it into the Firebase field of your Node.RED setup

If you want to use your existing project, you can also consider reaching out to Firebase support to get your existing database moved to the US.

But doesn't the real-time database get your data according to the time-zone? Does moving it to United States (us-central-1) affect the efficiency as I am living in Asia?

"But doesn't the real-time database get your data according to the time-zone?" Nope. "Does moving it to United States (us-central-1) affect the efficiency as I am living in Asia?" Yup, but it'll be your only option until Node.RED adds an option to enter the full Firebase Realtime Database URL. --- Also see: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers]
